# Irrationality Result

Tags: riemann-zeta, irrational-numbers

I have recently derived the following result: for any odd positive integer $k$, one of $\zeta(k)$ and $\zeta(k,2/3)$ is irrational.

I cannot find this result anywhere. Is it already known?

Thank you for any information.

Comment: I take it that by "one", you mean "at least one", rather than "exactly one".

Comment: Yes...at least one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be found in "On the Hurwitz Function for Rational Arguments", by V. Adamchik,
[https://viterbi-web.usc.edu/~adamchik/articles/AMC.pdf](https://viterbi-web.usc.edu/%7Eadamchik/articles/AMC.pdf)

Comment: Excellent reference